# How to apply any font in XSL file used to prepare an HTML file

Tags: html, xslt

We have an .xsl file in which we write the tags, tables etc..
This .xsl file is then converted to .html for end user.

```
    <xsl:template name="test_file">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="t1"  bgcolor="White">
          <tr>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                          <font color="Red">
                            <b>Sales Report</b>
                        </font>
                </td>
.
.
.
.
```

We use tables, containg rows, data in the xsl file.

How can we set the font of table rows/data to any font like arial, times new roman etc.?
Is there any list of font name avaliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set fonts with css in the xsl document. Code is untested, but hope it puts you on the right track.

```
<xsl:template match="/"><style type="text/css>

    .someclass {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    }

    .someclass1 {
    font-family: Sans;
    font-size: 8px;
    }

    TABLE.table1 {
    size:landscape;
    }

</style>

<xsl:template name="test_file">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="t1"  bgcolor="White">
          <tr class="someclass">
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                          <font color="Red">
                            <b class="someclass1">Sales Report</b>
                          </font>
                </td>
```

Comment: Thank you Raalph

Comment: Your inputs and https://www.way2tutorial.com/xml/xml-xslt-css-stylesheet.php helped me to set font.